# Two matrices satisfying reshaping relationship

Tags: matrices, permutations, matrix-equations

I am looking for two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that:

$$A\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c \\ d & e & f \\g & h & i \\j & k & l \\m & n & o \\p & q & r \\\end{bmatrix}B = \begin{bmatrix}a & d & b & e & c & f\\ g & j & h & k & i & l \\ m & p & n & q & o & r\end{bmatrix}$$

Can anyone tell me whether such matrices exist and, if so, give their values and, if not, disprove that such matrices can exist?

Comment: Letting your matrix in the middle be called $X$, the only way for $AXB$ to result in the desired shape is for $A$ to be a $3\times 6$ matrix and for $B$ to be a $3\times 6$ matrix as well.  Now, note that $AX$ will be a $3\times 3$ matrix.  Looking at the $3\times 3$ matrix $AX$ we effectively have nine equations but eighteen unknowns... that is to say, by having multiplied $X$ by $A$ we have blurred the distinction between each of your values $a,b,c,\dots$.

Comment: That is to say, in much the same way as how adding two values together, by looking only at the sum we don't know which values they were and can't separate them, whatever it was that $A$ did to $X$ when they were multiplied, we've done this in a way that we've lost information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no; no such matrices exist.

One proof is as follows: suppose for contradiction that such an $A,B$ exist.  Then if we take $a=j=n=1$ and set all other entries equal to zero, then we find that 
$$
A \pmatrix{
1\\
\\
\\
1\\
&1&\\&} B=\pmatrix{1\\&1\\&&1&&&}. 
$$
Note that the matrix on the right has rank $3$.  However, for any $M$, we have $\operatorname{rank}(AMB) \leq \operatorname{rank}(M)$.

Comment: Ah yes I see! Thank you!

Comment: @daw $M$ in this case is the rank-2 (tall, sparse) matrix.  $AMB$ is the rank-3 matrix on the right.